# Is there a way to reset all views when the user moves on from an activity?

Tags: android, reset

I have some edit texts in my activity. When the user types in them and doesn't save them, and the person leaves my activity, I would like all these edittexts to be empty again next time the user comes back.

Right now, it leaves the activity and goes back to it with the text still written in. I would like it to be empty.

This is quite good :

```
protected void onResume() {
    final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittextname);
    final EditText editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittextnumber);
    final EditText editText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittextaddress);
    super.onResume();
    editText.setText("");
    editText2.setText("");
    editText3.setText("");
}
```

But I also have some check boxes and radio buttons which keep the user's 
selections, even though the user has moved on from the activity.

Is there a way of resetting all views, rather than preserving the 
user's last used state?

Comment: why don't you just finish the current activity every time the user leaves?

Answer (score 0):

`android:noHistory="true"` between the activity tags in the Manifest file does the trick.